# Why doesn't it apply weighting windows?

Tags: matlab, filter, signals, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I created GUI where i can filter signals, using null-phase and min-phase filters at certain frequencies.If I want to avoid Gibbs effects I use Weighting windows on filters (zero and null phase). I have a feeling that Weighting windows don't apply, and signals' frequencies don't change on filters' frequencies, but all of this works then I execute it just in file.m except GUI.So, why don't Weighting windows apply?

```
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global select N contents contents2 

select=get(hObject,'Value');
switch select
    case 1
       %Hamming window
for k=1:1:N
   handles.w(k)=(0.54-0.46*cos(2*pi*k/N));
end 
    case 2
      %Hann window
for k=1:1:N
   handles.w(k)=0.5*(1-cos(2*pi*k/N));
end  
    case 3
     %Triangle window
for k=1:1:N
   handles.w(k)=1-abs((k-(N-1)/2)/N/2);
end   
    case 4
     %Cosine window
for k=1:1:N
   handles.w(k)=cos(pi*k/(N-1)-pi/2);
end   
    case 5
      %Blackman window
a0=0.42;
a1=0.5;
a2=0.08;
for k=1:1:N
   handles.w(k)=a0-a1*cos(2*pi*k/(N-1))+a2*cos(4*pi*k/(N-1));
end  
    case 6
    %Rectangle window
for k=1:1:N
   handles.w(k)=1;
end    

end
if contents2==1%если первый сигнал
    if contents==1%если нуль фазовый
handles.zerofilterw=fft(handles.zerofilter.*handles.w);
handles.fftsig1=fft(handles.sig1);
handles.filtersig1=handles.zerofilterw.*handles.fftsig1;
handles.filtsig1=real(ifft(handles.filtersig1));  

axes(handles.axes1);plot(handles.t-0.5,handles.filtsig1)
title('After zero phase Filtering signal 1')
grid on

axes(handles.axes2);plot(handles.nyqvuist,fftshift(abs(handles.filtersig1)));
title('After filtering in zero phase  frequency domain1')
grid on
    else
handles.minfilterw=fft(handles.minfilter.*handles.w);
handles.fftsig1=fft(handles.sig1);
handles.filtersig1=handles.minfilterw.*handles.fftsig1;
handles.filtsig1=real(ifft(handles.filtersig1));  

axes(handles.axes1);plot(handles.t-0.5,handles.filtsig1)
title('After  min phase Filtering signal 1')
grid on

axes(handles.axes2);plot(handles.nyqvuist,fftshift(abs(handles.filtersig1)));
title('After filtering in min phase frequency domain1')    
grid on
    end

else

    if contents==1%если нуль фазовый
handles.zerofilterw=fft(handles.zerofilter.*handles.w);
handles.fftsig2=fft(handles.sig2);
handles.filtersig2=handles.zerofilterw.*handles.fftsig2;
handles.filtsig2=real(ifft(handles.filtersig2));  

axes(handles.axes1);plot(handles.t-0.5,handles.filtsig2)
title('After zero phase Filtering signal 2')
grid on

axes(handles.axes2);plot(handles.nyqvuist,fftshift(abs(handles.filtersig2)));
title('After filtering in zero phase  frequency domain2')
grid on
    else
handles.minfilterw=fft(handles.minfilter.*handles.w);
handles.fftsig2=fft(handles.sig2);
handles.filtersig2=handles.minfilterw.*handles.fftsig2;
handles.filtsig2=real(ifft(handles.filtersig2));  

axes(handles.axes1);plot(handles.t-0.5,handles.filtsig2)
title('After  min phase Filtering signal 2')
grid on

axes(handles.axes2);plot(handles.nyqvuist,fftshift(abs(handles.filtersig2)));
title('After filtering in min phase frequency domain2')    
grid on
    end   
end


guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? It is unclear to me what problem you are seeing. It would help if you posted a short bit of code that creates a sample signal and applies your filter (the code you post here is way too long to read!) See [mcve].

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've tried make it shorter.

Comment: This still has a lot of confounding stuff, the smaller you make the example, the easier it is to spot issues. You use global variables, these are hard to debug, it’s better to use alternate methods. For example, it looks like `switch select` is where the filter is applied, but I don’t see where `select` is defined or set.

Comment: @CrisLuengo select is supposed to belong to uibuttongroup1 where I can choose proper radiobutton (kind of weighting window).

Comment: OK, so now you’re removed even more code. But I still can’t see how or where `select` is defined. It is read from a GUI object, but which one? Where? What value does it have? This is the core concept of a [mcve]: it needs to be not only short, but also complete, so that I can copy-paste the code and see what you are seeing. That is the only way that guarantees other people will be able to understand the problem. If you can’t make a short example that reproduces your problem, you’ll have to learn to debug your code yourself.

Comment: Try setting a break point (by clicking on the left margin in the MATLAB Editor) at the beginning of this function, then run your code. Now you’ll be able to step through your code line by line, and see what value `select` receives, what values the window will be given, etc.